# How to use symbol server with gitlab

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, debug-symbols

We are using Gitlab version 16.7 and I want to create a debug profile for my dotnet class library projects. But I couldn't find a detailed documentation on this topic. Below you can find my CI/CD settings. I couldn't find where to upload the .snupkg packages, I tried to upload it to "https://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project-id/packages/nuget/symbolpackage" or I tried to upload it to "https://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project-id/packages/nuget/index.json" but visual studio couldn't see the .snupkg file in both. How do you debug your projects with Gitlab?

```
stages:
- build
- deploy

image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: '*/*/'

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  policy: pull-push

before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  - 'export VERSION_SUFFIX=beta$CI_PIPELINE_ID'

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --configuration Release'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet pack -c Release /p:PackageVersion=1.0.0-$VERSION_SUFFIX --output $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY --version-suffix $VERSION_SUFFIX --include-symbols -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg'
    - 'dotnet nuget add source "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/nuget" --name gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text'
    - 'dotnet nuget push $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY/*.nupkg --source gitlab'
  environment: production
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I couldn't find a detailed documentation on this topic.

Maybe because it is not yet officially supported.
See [gitlab-org epic 10825](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10825):

> Nuget symbol package capability (`.snupkg`) was added [in 14.1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/64803)
>
> The "[Symbol packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/#symbol-packages)" documentation stayes:
>
> > Consuming symbol packages is not yet guaranteed using clients such as Visual Studio or dotnet-symbol. The `.snupkg` files are available for download through the UI or the API.

A week ago (Dec. 19th, 2023), that [epic says](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10825#note_1701240263)

> The feature has been deployed to gitlab.com and can be used after enabling the symbol server capability in the group's package settings.
>
> For now, only portable PDB symbol files are supported.
>
> More details at "[NuGet packages in the package registry / Use the package registry as a symbol server](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/#use-the-package-registry-as-a-symbol-server)"

---

> What don't I understand is if the pdb file and the `.snupkg` files are the same thing?
>
> GitLab has two different endpoints, one is "`/packages/nuget/symbolfiles`" and the other is "`/packages/nuget/symbolpackage`": which one should I send my `.snupkg` files to?

To clarify:

- The PDB ([Program Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)) files store debugging information for a given assembly (like a DLL or EXE). They contain data like function names, variable names, and line numbers that help debuggers correlate executable code with the source code that produced it.
- The [`.snupkg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg) files are NuGet symbol packages. They are essentially containers for PDB files and possibly other related debugging information. They are designed to be uploaded to a symbol server or a NuGet feed, allowing debuggers to automatically fetch the corresponding PDB files when needed.

In the context of GitLab, you have two different endpoints:

1. **[`/packages/nuget/symbolfiles`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/#use-the-package-registry-as-a-symbol-server)**: This endpoint is likely meant for directly uploading PDB files.
   This assumes, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/#use-the-package-registry-as-a-symbol-server), that you did enable the `nuget_symbol_server_enabled` namespace setting with the [GraphQL API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#packagesettings).
2. **[`/packages/nuget/symbolpackage`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages/nuget.html#upload-a-symbol-package-file)**: This endpoint is for uploading `.snupkg` packages, which are the NuGet symbol packages containing the PDB files.

Since you are working with `.snupkg` files, you should use the "`/packages/nuget/symbolpackage`" endpoint. Your CI/CD pipeline needs to push these `.snupkg` packages to this endpoint, allowing GitLab to serve as a symbol server.

The relevant part of your CI/CD configuration for pushing the `.snupkg` files will be:

```yaml
- 'dotnet nuget push $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY/*.snupkg --source gitlab'
```

Make sure that the source 'gitlab' in the `dotnet nuget push` command is correctly configured to point to the `/packages/nuget/symbolpackage` endpoint on your GitLab instance.

---

> Another question that confuses me is that the pipeline above saves the package output in the package registry.
> When I look at the package details, `.nupkg` and `.snupkg` are next to each other: do I need to send the `.snupkg` files to one of the places I mentioned in my previous question?

The presence of both `.nupkg` and `.snupkg` files in your package registry is a good sign, indicating that your CI/CD pipeline is successfully uploading these packages.

1. [`.nupkg` files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershellget-3.x#using-manual-download-to-acquire-a-package) are the NuGet packages containing your compiled code, resources, and metadata necessary for using your library.
2. `.snupkg` files are symbol packages contain the debugging symbols (PDB files) for your library. They are separate from the `.nupkg` files but are related to them.

When you upload these packages to GitLab, they should be stored in the package registry, which serves as a repository for both types of files. Your pipeline already seems to be configured correctly for this.

That means:

- You do not need to send the `.snupkg` files to a different place: The fact that they are stored alongside the `.nupkg` files in the package registry is the intended behavior. That setup allows users and tools that consume your NuGet packages to also find and use the corresponding symbol packages for debugging.
- The `/packages/nuget/symbolpackage` endpoint in GitLab is the correct destination for your `.snupkg` files. That is typically handled by your CI/CD pipeline script, as you have already set up with the `dotnet nuget push` command.

---

> Based on your answers, it seems that I don't need to modify my pipeline file, I just need to place the code you suggested (`dotnet push ..... "*.snupkg"`) at the bottom of my pipeline file.
>
> But in my pipeline file we didn't give the endpoint that should be transferred for the symbolpackage, in this case which URL should I define for the `symbolserver`? According to the discussion, only pdb is currently supported, which means that the "`symbolpackage`" endpoint doesn't work.
> How can I transfer pdb files to the "`symbolfiles`" endpoint?
>
> Transferring the pdb file to the "`symbolfiles`" endpoint every time the pipeline runs and the packaging phase is completed seems to solve my problem.  Do you have a pipeline code suggestion for this? How do I ensure that the pdb file is created during the pipeline run and how do I send it?

True: Since the `.snupkg` endpoint is not currently functional for your needs, you will be focusing on the `/packages/nuget/symbolfiles` endpoint to transfer PDB files.

So make sure your build process is creating PDB files. That is typically done by default in .NET projects, especially when building in the `Debug` configuration. However, if you are building in `Release` mode, make sure to include the necessary flags to generate PDB files. The `DebugType` property in your `.csproj` files controls this.

You need a script in your pipeline to identify and upload the PDB files to GitLab's `/packages/nuget/symbolfiles` endpoint. That process might involve using `curl` or a similar tool to make HTTP requests to GitLab's API. Your script will need to include authentication against your GitLab instance, typically using a CI job token or a personal access token.

That means your `deploy` stage might look like this:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --configuration Release /p:DebugType=portable'  # Make sure PDB files are generated
    - 'dotnet pack -c Release /p:PackageVersion=1.0.0-$VERSION_SUFFIX --output $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
    - 'dotnet nuget push $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY/*.nupkg --source gitlab'
    - for file in $(find $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY -name '*.pdb'); do
        curl --request POST --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form "file=@$file" "https://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/nuget/symbolfiles"
      done
  environment: production
```

The `/p:DebugType=portable` flag means portable PDB files are created. Portable PDBs are generally recommended for .NET Core and later projects.

The `find` command locates all PDB files in your output directory. Adjust the path if your PDB files are located elsewhere.

The `curl` command uploads each PDB file to the GitLab API. Replace `https://mygitlab.com` with your actual GitLab instance URL, and make sure `$CI_PROJECT_ID` is correctly set in your CI environment. The script uses `JOB-TOKEN` for authentication. Make sure your CI job token has the necessary permissions to upload to the repository.

---

> I get that error for every pdb files while post-process: `{"error":"404 Not Found"}`

The URL used in the `curl` command might not be correct. Double-check the API endpoint provided by GitLab for uploading symbol files. Make sure it matches the one you are using in the script.

And double-check that the `$CI_PROJECT_ID` in your script does correspond to your project's ID in GitLab. A mismatch here could result in the endpoint not being found.

Verify that the CI job token (`$CI_JOB_TOKEN`) has the necessary permissions to upload files to the repository. If the token lacks the required privileges, it might lead to a `404` error.

You can add debugging lines to help diagnose the issue (`curl --verbose`, and echo lines):

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --configuration Release /p:DebugType=portable'
    - 'dotnet pack -c Release /p:PackageVersion=1.0.0-$VERSION_SUFFIX --output $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
    - 'dotnet nuget push $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY/*.nupkg --source gitlab'
    - for file in $(find $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY -name '*.pdb'); do
        echo "Uploading $file"
        curl --verbose --request POST --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form "file=@$file" "https://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/nuget/symbolfiles"
      done
  environment: production
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen this discussion but what I don't understand is if the pdb file and the .snupkg files are the same thing? Gitlab has two different endpoints, one is "/packages/nuget/symbolfiles" and the other is "/packages/nuget/symbolpackage" which one should I send my .snupkg files to.

Comment: Another question that confuses me is that the pipeline above saves the package output in the package registry. When I look at the package details, .nupkg and .snupkg are next to each other, do I need to send the .snupkg files to one of the places I mentioned in my previous question?

Comment: @CodAvo I have edited the answer to address your second comment.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Based on your answers, it seems that I don't need to modify my pipeline file, I just need to place the code you suggested (dotnet push ..... "*.snupkg") at the bottom of my pipeline file. But in my pipeline file we didn't give the endpoint that should be transferred for the symbolpackage, in this case which url should I define for the symbolserver? According to the discussion, only pdb is currently supported, which means that the "symbolpackage" endpoint doesn't work. How can I transfer pdb files to the "symbolfiles" endpoint?

Comment: Transferring the pdb file to the "symbolfiles" endpoint every time the pipeline runs and the packaging phase is completed seems to solve my problem.  Do you have a pipeline code suggestion for this? How do I ensure that the pdb file is created during the pipeline run and how do I send it?

Comment: By the way, this topic will be a touchstone for many people because I have not found a clear solution elsewhere and the terms are very overlapping and confusing.

Comment: @CodAvo OK, I have edited the question to address your comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try your solution tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I gave that error for every pdb files while post process -> {"error":"404 Not Found"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256393/discussion-between-vonc-and-codavo).

Comment: I have tried everything but there seems to be no way to upload the pdb files.